# listbox does not pass string to google script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I select a user from listbox, the `onChange()` event triggers a function. It should pass a string to the function.  Then the code finds the user's password and returns it for comparison.  The following is the code which works fine if I hard code the user value, but not when I select it from the listbox.

```
function addClients(clients){
  $('#customer').empty(); 
  $('#customer').append('<option> ---- Choose a user ----</option>');
  for (var i in clients) {
    $('#customer').append('<option>'+clients[i]+'</option>');
    $('#customer').trigger("chosen:updated"); 
  }
}
```

getval function:

```
function getval(sel){
    var usrpass = google.script.run.getuserpass(sel.value);
    alert(usrpass);
}
```

the function in code.gs is as follows

```
function getuserpass(userval){
 var usrpass = "";
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheet id");
 var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet();
 var data = sheet.getRange(3, 3, sheet.getLastRow(),5).getValues();; 
 for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){
 // iterate row by row and examine data in column A
 if(data[n][0].toString().match(userval)==userval){ usrpass = data[n][4]};
 }
 return usrpass;
}
```

Why does the return value come back as undefined rather than the password.

If I hardcode username in the function and run the function, then the return value is the value in the fifth column.

Comment: Put a `Logger.log('value is: ' + sel.value);` statement at the top of your `getval()` function, run the code, the VIEW the LOGS.  Is the value of `sel.value` what you expect?

Comment: thanks. it returns a string of the listbox name, id number and text. i need to get the value as seen in the list box and not the full text

Comment: Is this an HTML Dialog Box?  Why are you using `google.script.run()`.  `google.script.run` is only for being put into an HTML `<script>` tag.  Can you show the list box?  Is it a list box in HTML?

Comment: it is an html listbox constructed using query and data from spreadsheet. function addClients(clients){
  $('#customer').empty();
  $('#customer').append('<option> ---- Choose a user ----</option>');
  for (var i in clients) {
    $('#customer').append('<option>'+clients[i]+'</option>');
    $('#customer').trigger("chosen:updated");
  }
}

Comment: what is `sel`?  Is it an object?  Is it a form object?  How is `sel` getting passed to the `getval` function?

Comment: change event for the list box passes "this" to the function getval. <select name="customer" id="customer" onchange= "getval(this)" data-native-menu="true" data-role="none">

Comment: What is the sandbox setting?  Have you tried changing it?

Comment: var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
                   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

Answer (score 0):

Try structuring the code like this:

```
<script>
  function onSuccess(returnVal) {
    alert('Success! ' + returnVal);
  };

  function getval(sel){

    var selectValue = sel.value;
    console.log('selectValue: ' + selectValue);

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
      .getuserpass(sel.value);
  };

</script>
```

You can iterate through the object to see what is really in it, as a debugging test.

```
for (var propertyVal in sel) {
  console.log('this property: ' + propertyVal);
  console.log('this value: ' + sel[propertyVal]);
};
```

And see what is really in the object.

Comment: yes this is not a string but the property returns a lot of values

Comment: the function getuserpass does not get called at all!

Comment: See updated answer.  You need a `withSuccessHandler` to handle the return from the `gs` code.  I previously made a mistake by putting a `Logger.log()` where it should have been `console.log()`